# Django Fullcalendar ajax no showing events

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Hi I can't get events from ajax call to calendar please help

template:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 .....
  events:{
    url:'{% url 'rezerwacje' %}',
    type: 'GET',
  },
```

url.py

```
url(r'^rezerwacje/json2/', views.RezerwacjeLista, name='rezerwacje'),
```

views.py

```
def RezerwacjeLista(request):
    if request.is_ajax():

    try:
        start = request.GET.get('start', False)
        print start
        end = request.GET.get('end',False)
    except ValueError:
        start = datetime.now()
        end = start + timedelta(days=7)

    rezerwacje = Rezerwacje.objects.filter(start__gte=start).filter(end__lte=end)
    json_list = []
    lista = []
    for rezerwacja in rezerwacje:
        id = rezerwacja.id
        start = rezerwacja.start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        stanowisko = rezerwacja.stanowisko.nazwa
        end = rezerwacja.end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        kolor = rezerwacja.kolor
        status = rezerwacja.status
        #allDay = False

        json_entry = {"id":'1', 'start':start, 'end':end,'resourceId':stanowisko, 'kolor':kolor, 'status': status}
        json_list.append(json_entry)
        lista = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json_list))
    return HttpResponse(lista, content_type='application/json')
```

That view returns json:

```
{'kolor': '1', 'status': 1, 'end': '2017-05-03 15:00:00', 'resourceId': 'K1', 'start': '2017-05-03 14:00:00', 'id': '1'}
```

That is good but when i select date in calendar there is no result on events. In response i get url and json

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rezerwacje/json2/?start=2017-05-03&end=2017-05-04&_=1493937740198
```

How to pass result to ajax?

Comment: Could you verify that your browser is sending an AJAX request? Try checking your browser's Dev Tools in the Network tab.

Comment: yes, sending good request

Comment: So the AJAX request is getting sent. Could you edit your question to include the response of the AJAX request?

Comment: It would be useful to compare the response you get back from the AJAX request vs. opening the URL in a browser window.